# can't launch kali-linux GUI (based on WSL 2) with a shortcut on Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, wsl2, windows-terminal

I can't find any way to launch the kali-linux GUI with a shortcut and I've tried a lot of methods! 
I don't want everytime to search for "Kali Linux" on Start, then open it, run the two commands everytime, 
 ⠀$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /tmp/.X11-unix 
 ⠀$ kex 
 I just want it to open directly! 
I've already tried changing the .json file of Windows Terminal settings or creating a batch file 
but I've no succeeded. 
I basically need a shortcut to open the kali-linux terminal with pre-loaded those two commands, 
so the GUI will open directly. 
(note that I've set Ubuntu as the default WSL 2 distro and I don't want to change this option) 
Please help, thanks!

Comment: Have you set this up and do you start Kali as described in [Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/)? If not, or if you're not sure, I'd suggest deleting the current installation and reinstalling it exactly as described there. Also you should explain what exactly you've tried, and give a step-by-step workflow how exactly you start it so others can see if your issues are reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just solved it by myself... I've looked better through the [Win-kex documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/) and I found that they provide Windows Terminal profile configs you can paste directly in the `.json` settings file: I used the `Advanced Window Mode`.

From the Windows Terminal settings, I duplicated the `kali-linux` profile just to obtain a new unique profile guid, then from the `.json` settings file I've edited the profile name from `kali-linux (Copy)` to `Win-kex` and I also edited the `commandline` and the `startingDirectory` by pasting those entries on the documentation.

I created a batch file where I coded a way to start Win-kex and exit the Terminal automatically, then finally I converted it to an `.exe` using Advanced BAT to EXE Converter PRO, I stored it in a folder located to Program Files and I added a shortcut to it called "kali-linux" to my Start Menu.

So now, when I want to open kali-linux distro, I just search for "kali-linux" on Start Menu and open the program.

---

**Windows Terminal profile** - add this code to the `.json` settings file, along with the other profiles:

```
            {
                "guid": "{32blc95n-e814-739i-064t-w794h53755f4}",
                "hidden": true,
                "name": "Win-kex",
                "icon": "ms-appx:///ProfileIcons/{32blc95n-e814-739i-064t-w794h53755f4}.png",
                "commandline": "wsl -d kali-linux sudo mount -o remount,rw /tmp/.X11-unix; kex --wtstart -s",
                "startingDirectory": "//wsl$/kali-linux/home/<username>"
            }
```

---

**program [klLauncher.exe]** - store it in `C:\Program Files\klLauncher`:
[download](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1026163170865324082/1093985523984502935/klLauncher.exe)

---

**shortcut** - rename its extension to `.lnk` and place it in the Start Menu:
[download](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1093986360777523321/1093986515551518760/kali-linux.lnk)

---

**.ico file** - it's the icon, store it somewhere and add it to the Start Menu shortcut:
[download](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1093985960015974400/1093986100411912312/klLauncher.ico)

Answer (score 1):

Kali is not well suited to command - non-GUI as you have and WSL is for running Linux commands and is not well suited to be a virtual machine app.

Run Kali in a Virtual Machine App (VMware, Hyper-V) and that works very well.

I am in Kali 2023.1 now running as a VM inside VMware. Works splendidly well.

Remember that Kali is a different kind of OS and known to be unfriendly.  It is Linux, but heavy on security Apps and short on GUI user tools. Most Kali users are interested in the Security Apps.

Comment: No, I just want to use the GUI offered by them via Win-kex, the problem isn't kali-linux, but the usage of the Windows Terminal! I have to find a successful way to pass commands on the kali-linux profile on the Terminal

Comment: WSL is not suited to that. I have used Ubuntu (Store) for this but Kali did not work.

Comment: @martinotecco - What exactly is "Win-kex"?

Comment: win-kex has been a way to start Kali. in WSL  As noted, I did not find it to work very well.